# Cumulative Mul: Write a function cumulative_mul that mutates the Tree t so that each node’s label becomes the product of its label

Tags: python, tree

Write a function cumulative_mul that mutates the Tree t so that each node’s label becomes the product of its label and all labels in the subtrees rooted at the node.

Hint: Consider carefully when to do the mutation of the tree and whether that mutation should happen before or after processing the subtrees

```py
class Tree:
    def __init__(self, label, branches=[]):
        for b in branches:
            assert isinstance(b, Tree)
        self.label = label
        self.branches = list(branches)

    def is_leaf(self):
        return not self.branches
```

```py
def cumulative_mul(t):
    """Mutates t so that each node's label becomes the product of all labels in
    the corresponding subtree rooted at t.

    >>> t = Tree(1, [Tree(3, [Tree(5)]), Tree(7)])
    >>> cumulative_mul(t)
    >>> t
    Tree(105, [Tree(15, [Tree(5)]), Tree(7)])
    >>> otherTree = Tree(2, [Tree(1, [Tree(3), Tree(4), Tree(5)]), Tree(6, [Tree(7)])])
    >>> cumulative_mul(otherTree)
    >>> otherTree
    Tree(5040, [Tree(60, [Tree(3), Tree(4), Tree(5)]), Tree(42, [Tree(7)])])
    """
    "*** YOUR CODE HERE ***"
    if t.is_leaf():
        return
    for b in t.branches:
        cumulative_mul(b)
        if isinstance(b, Tree):
            t.label *= b.label
```

My English may not explain my thoughts clearly, forgive me.
I can get a rough idea of the structure, the basic idea use recursion is when it's leaf return the value and when it's a subtree return the product of the labels of the subtree. the structure happened layer to layer.But what confused me is how is works when you need to multiply two labels of subtrees.

Comment: Where have you defined the `branches` attribute? Please add the definition of your `Tree` class.

Comment: *"what confused me is how is works when you need to multiply"*: but your code is doing it here: `t.label *= b.label`? What is not clear? What is your question?

Comment: i wonder why their is no product of the two b.label

Comment: But there is **is** a product of the two labels: one is called `t.label` and the other `b.label`. Do you know what `*=` does? Or is there something in the output that is not as you want it?

Comment: i know a*= b --> a = a*b

Comment: So then what is your question: the multiplication happens?

Comment: i just can't figure out which layer is  the t.label and b.label in

Comment: What do you mean with layer? `b` is a child of `t`.

Comment: Turan-Yahya Gazizuly's answer give me an idea, what i confused was  subtree_product is missing in this code.

Comment: I wrote in a comment below their answer that they implement the same thing, but with an extra name. But using that additional temporary name doesn't make a difference, the result is the same. Your code puts the intermediate products immediately in `t.label`, why they put the intermediate product in a temporary variable, and then copy that into `t.label`, which is obviously the same as in your code.

Comment: Your are really friendly and helpful! But maybe I lack some understanding in recursion, every time when I try to figure out in mind the whole process but  always fails. Do you have any suggestions.

Comment: You could use a debugger and have it step through the code with a small input tree. Inspect how variables change.

Answer (score 0):

To handle the multiplication of `labels` from different `subtrees`, you can calculate the `product` of the `labels` of each `subtree` first and then multiply it with the current `node's label`.

```js
# class to represent the object for problem
class Tree: 
    def __init__(self, label, branches=[]): # init function to create object
        self.label = label
        self.branches = branches

    def is_leaf(self): # check the 'self' is leaf
        return not self.branches

# function to manipulate with object 'Tree'
def cumulative_mul(t):
    if t.is_leaf(): # check by using method 
        return

    subtree_product = 1  # Initialize product for the current subtree
    for b in t.branches: # cycle 
        cumulative_mul(b)
        if isinstance(b, Tree): # check
            subtree_product *= b.label  # Multiply labels of subtrees

    t.label *= subtree_product  # Multiply the current node's label by the subtree product

# Test cases for problem
t = Tree(1, [Tree(3, [Tree(5)]), Tree(7)])
cumulative_mul(t) # run test cases
print(t.label)  # Output: 105

otherTree = Tree(2, [Tree(1, [Tree(3), Tree(4), Tree(5)]), Tree(6, [Tree(7)])])
cumulative_mul(otherTree) # run test cases 
print(otherTree.label)  # Output: 5040
```

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question. The asker already has the code for doing this (but without the intermediate `subtree_product` name).